# Fetching data, get object, but still have error. Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, fetch-api

Cannot fix this error.
I receive data (object) from thingspeak.com via fetch method. Then I want to render three values from that object: name,  temperature and time. I can see temperature and name but not time.
Here is my error in console:
**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0').**
Any ideas?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const App = () => {

  const [channelInfo, setChannelInfo] = useState({});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [dateWithOffset, setDateWithOffset] = useState(null);

  const getThermoData = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/618304/fields/1.json?results=1`);
    const data = await response.json();
    setChannelInfo(data);
    setIsLoading(false);
    timeConverter();
  }

  const timeConverter = () => {
    const channelDate = channelInfo.feeds[0].created_at;
    const date = new Date(channelDate);
    const timestampWithOffset = date.getTime();
    setDateWithOffset(new Date(timestampWithOffset));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getThermoData();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='card'>
      {
        isLoading ? <p className='loading'>Loading...</p> : <>
          <h5 className='channel-name no-select'>{channelInfo.channel.name}</h5>
          <p className='temperature-value no-select'>{channelInfo.feeds[0].field1}</p>
          <h5 className='channel-time no-select'>{dateWithOffset}</h5>
        </>
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Simwu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `timeConverter` just after setting the new state with `setChannelInfo(data);` will throw you an exception due to 1) Initial `channelInfo` value is `{}` so there is no `.feeds[0].created_at` and 2) calling `setChannelInfo` will not update the variable immediately. It will be updated on next render only.

You can switch to `useMemo`, add `undefined` check, change initial state of `channelInfo` to undefined.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [channelInfo, setChannelInfo] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const dateWithOffset = useMemo(() => {
    if (!channelInfo) return "";

    const channelDate = channelInfo.feeds[0].created_at;
    const date = new Date(channelDate);
    const timestampWithOffset = date.getTime();
    return new Date(timestampWithOffset).toString();
  }, [channelInfo]);

  const getThermoData = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/618304/fields/1.json?results=1`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    setChannelInfo(data);
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getThermoData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="card">
      {isLoading ? (
        <p className="loading">Loading...</p>
      ) : (
        <>
          <h5 className="channel-name no-select">{channelInfo.channel.name}</h5>
          <p className="temperature-value no-select">
            {channelInfo.feeds[0].field1}
          </p>
          <h5 className="channel-time no-select">{dateWithOffset}</h5>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Yes! It works just fine! Thanks a lot! Now it's time to read useMemo hook documentation.